# Generating Different Colours On the JVectorMap Regions Based On The Range Of Values

Tags: jvectormap

I'm using  JVectorMap for creating World Map..

As part of my JVectorMap im displaying on the regions CountryName  with Population..

My Question is:

How to show differrent colours for the regions (countries) based on population ranges.

Ex: For 1-1000 population i have to show red colour. 
    For 1000-5000 population i have to show blue colour.

I'm using code like this.But it is not displaying different colours based on the range of population

```
var mapData = {
  "AF": 1000,
  "AL": 5000,
  "DZ": 20000,
  ...
};

     try{
                        $('#id').vectorMap(
                        {
                            map : 'world_mill_en',
                            series : {
                                regions : [ {
                                    initial : {
                                        fill : 'white',
                                        "fill-opacity" : 1,
                                        stroke : 'none',
                                        "stroke-width" : 0,
                                        "stroke-opacity" : 1
                                    },
                                    hover : {
                                        "fill-opacity" : 0.8
                                    },
                                    selected : {
                                        fill : 'yellow'
                                    },
                                    selectedHover : {},
                                    values : mapData,
                                    scale : [  '#C8EEFF', '#0071A4' ],
                                    normalizeFunction : 'polynomial'
                                } ]
                            },
                            onRegionLabelShow : function(e, el, code) {
                                el.html(el.html()+' (Population - '+mapData[code]+')');
                            }
                        });
            }
    catch(err){
            alert(err);
        }
```

Can any one help me in displaying differnt colours for the regions based on the range of population......?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `JSON` with count and color codes like this according to your regions and colors.

```
var colorData = {
     "1" : "#C8EEFF", 
     "2" : "#0071A4",
     "3" : "#C8EEFF", 
     "4" : "#0071A4",
     "5" : "#C8EEFF", 
     "6" : "#0071A4"
}
```

and pass this `JSON` to the `scale : colorData`. Hope it helps you.